Remove everything in string after the first occurrence of a word
I have a dataframe with a column consisting of strings. I want to trim the strings in the column such that everything is removed after the first appearance of a given word. The words are in this list:
words_to_trim_after = ['test', 'hello', 'very good']

So if I have a dataframe such as the following
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['test this is a test bla bla', 'hello bla bla this is a test', 'very good qwerty this is nice']})

I want to end up with
df_end = pd.DataFrame({'a':['test', 'hello', 'very good']})


You can use split
def trim_after_first_word(s, words):
        for word in words:
            parts = s.split(word, maxsplit=1)
            if len(parts) > 1:
                return word
        return None


For each word in words, check if it is on your string txt contains it, then split and save the first part extended with the word.
Once done for each word, return the shortest result ('test hello very good' should only return 'test').
Therefore, you will have removed everything after the first occurrence of a word.
def remove_after_first_word(txt, words):
  candidates = [txt]
  for word in words:
    if not word in txt:
      continue
    candidates.append(txt.split(word)[0]+word)
  return min(candidates, key=len)


re module can also be considered. re.sub can replace anything you matched for anything you like.
The pattern '(?P<key>.*?{key}).*' match the key you passed and reserve the content before it and replace content after it to empty.
import re
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['test this is a test bla bla',
                  'bla bla hello bla bla  this is a test', 'very good werty this is nice']})
words_to_trim_after = ['test', 'hello', 'very good']


def trim_after_word(key, sentence): return re.sub(
    f'(?P<key>.*?{key}).*', '\g<key>', sentence)


for i in range(len(words_to_trim_after)):
    df['a'][i] = trim_after_word(words_to_trim_after[i], df["a"][i])
print(df['a'])


Here is a variant of the first answer but it chooses the first occurence of any of the words and not the first word in the list that appears. Also, it removes only the part of the string after the word and not the part before:
import pandas as pd

words_to_trim_after = ['test', 'hello', 'very good']

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['test this is a test bla bla', 'hello bla bla this is a test', 'very good qwerty this is nice', 'this string does not contain any the words']})

def parse_func(string: str):
    found = False
    index = len(string)
    for word in words_to_trim_after:
        if word in string:
            index = min(index, string.index(word) + len(word))
            found = True
    return string[:index] if found else None

df_end = df["a"].apply(parse_func)

print(df_end)

You can replace the "None" in the return by anything you want as the original string for example.

I opted for taking a slice of the string of the length of the word to trim for, then moving the index one step at a time. Finally, since we have 3 strings in words_to_trim_after we will have 3 candidates. I use the min function to choose the shortest string.
# recreate data frame
import pandas as pd
words_to_trim_after = ['test', 'hello', 'very good']
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['test this is a test bla bla', 'hello bla bla this is a test', 'very good qwerty this is nice']})


# solution
def trim_string(string, word):
  for i in range(len(string)-len(word)):
    candidate = string[i:i+len(word)]
    if candidate == word:
      return string[0:i+len(word)]
  return string

df["b"] = df["a"].apply(lambda string: min([trim_string(string, word) for word in words_to_trim_after], key=len))
df




index
a
b




0
test this is a test bla bla
test


1
hello bla bla this is a test
hello


2
very good qwerty this is nice
very good



